# how do I open <li> next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I've made a little navigation thingy at the top of my website. But, when you hover it, I want the options to open next to each other, instead of on top of each other.

I hope someone can help me out.

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50px;
}
ul li {
    position: relative;
}
li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 49px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    background:none;
    padding: 5px;
}
/* Fix IE. Hide from IE Mac */
 * html ul li {
    float: left;
}
* html ul li a {
    height: 1%;
}
/* End */
 li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
li:hover ul, li.over ul {
    display: block;
}
/* Fix IE. Hide from IE Mac */
 * html ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 1%;
}
* html ul li a {
    height: 1%;
}
/* End */
 #uno:hover {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

I do not have a link to the website because it's not online yet. If you need more information I can try to make a little demo but I thought, probably you will know what I mean.

Comment: I think a demo would be most useful. Try http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here's a awesome website to make demos mate. http://jsfiddle.net/. Plus I need to see your HTML structure.

Comment: You're hiding your CSS from *IE Mac*?? That software was discontinued **ten years ago**. I think it's now safe to assume that NOBODY is viewing your website with this browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS you have a `width:50px;` set on your `ul` tag which is stopping your links to align side by side.

Also add

```
ul li { display:inline;}
```

As elements are defaulted to `display:block`

http://jsfiddle.net/V3sTd/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should try replacing

```
display: block;
```

with

```
display:inline-block;
```